# Validating Credit Card Information - CVV Numbers

Tags: payment-gateway, credit-card, authorize.net, payment-processing

I am using authorize.net {aim} for my payment gateway. I am using test authorize for developer account.

I have used https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll with C# and it successfuly works without error.

But my client needs to validate the cvv [Card Verification Value]. How can this be done?

Answer (score 12):

Outside of checking the format for basic sanity (e.g. 3 or 4 digits depending on card), **the [CVV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Card_security_code) can only be validated by having a payment approved/authorized**, which should be done by your payment processor. See the [Transaction Types](http://developer.authorize.net/guides/AIM/Submitting_Transactions/Credit_Card_Transaction_Types.htm) documentation on .. *drum roll* .. authorize.net.

The [Luhn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) (or similar) checksum used on the card number is designed to catch simple *human entry errors*, such as number transposition, and does *not* guarantee that the number is valid - just that it *could* be valid. There is no need to have a similar checksum on the CVV due to it's small size (3 or 4 digits) and doing so would reduce the value space which somewhat defeats the purpose of the CVV ..

Oh, and please don't say you're storing CVVs? That's *very bad* :-(

Happy coding.

Comment: Not just very bad, it's a severe violation of the Payment Card Industry standards.

Answer (score 1):

you have to activate your ccv requirement on your authorize.net test account likewise on the live account for real credit card transaction.